# Issue with sendPasswordResetEmail() Function in Firebase-React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing a React project with Firebase integration, and I've come across an error when attempting to use the `sendPasswordResetEmail()` function from the Firebase Authentication module. The error message displayed is as follows:

> *services_firebaseConfig_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Dialog, TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { auth } from "../../services/firebaseConfig/config";

const ForgotPasswordDialog = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handlePasswordReset = async () => {
    try {
      await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
      setMessage("Email send to " + email + " please check your inbox");
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage("Error: " + error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose}>
      <div>
        <h2>Forgotten password</h2>
        {message && <p>{message}</p>}
        <TextField
          label="Email"
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Button onClick={handlePasswordReset}>Password reset</Button>
      </div>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default ForgotPasswordDialog;

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// a config adatok .env file-ban vannak a forráskódtól külön
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID,
};

//console.log("hahó" + firebaseConfig.apiKey);

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const fire_store = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

This issue is particularly puzzling, because all other aspects of the Firebase SDK seem to be functioning correctly in my application, including Authentication, Storage, and Firestore. Additionally, I have verified that there are no errors in my Firebase SDK configuration.

Could you please provide some guidance on what might be causing this issue with the `sendPasswordResetEmail()` function? I am uncertain whether this is related to the way I am importing or initializing Firebase in my project, or if it's an issue with the Firebase SDK itself.

Here are some details regarding my project setup:

- React Version: [18.2.0]
- Firebase SDK Version"firebase": "^10.7.1",

I have verified that there are no errors in my Firebase SDK configuration.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: share your code for the part your calling the sendPasswordResetEmail function.

Comment: Thank you! I have supplemented my question with the code